# cancan filter records by role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, roles, cancan, mask

very simple question here but I don't have the answer... ;-)

I just need to browse my user db by roles. I don't know how to match the role I'm looking for with the mask created by cancan

I tried:

`@users= User.role?('manager')` but of course it doesn't work.

Do you have the answer? Thanks!!

Comment: Do you mean in Ability.rb? And how are roles associated with users: User belongs_to Role?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got it. The answer was given by Ryan B. in his excellent railscasts:

Use this scope:

```
  scope :with_role, lambda { |role| {:conditions => "roles_mask & #{2**ROLES.index(role.to_s)} > 0"} }
```

and simply apply it this way:

```
@admins = User.with_role('admin')
```

Comment: That applies unless you store roles in the database.

Comment: The roles are stored in the database with a mask